# Difference between Chi^2, Chi^2/dof and R^2

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, r-squared

I have radioactive decay experiment (so the model is y = Ae^(-kt)) results and am (slowly) teaching myself mathematica to plot this. I want to output some measure for the goodness of fit, but am unsure what metric to use: Chi^2, Chi^2/dof, R^2, or some other thing I've not heard before?
Whilst I've used these things before they've all felt like black boxes, and I've always been instructed Chi^2 and R^2 approximately 1 is what you want, and that Chi^2 is usually the preferred metric. I've looked up a few online textbooks etc., but I would really it in more plain English (think a good ol' Explain it like I'm 5 description).
Happy to provide the data / graph if that helps.

Comment: The metric to use depends (*inter alia*) on the experimental design, your assumptions about how and why $y$ might differ from the model values, and how you are fitting the model to the data.  What information can you supply about these matters?

Comment: It an experiment for the decay of Phosphorus-31, it emits a positron, which upon interacting with an electron, emits 2 back to back photons, when the detector detects 2 pulses of light at almost the same time (within 5ns), it increments the count by 1. The detecto itself is a torus that surrounds the sample. The number of counts is sorted by channel (which is essentially the angle of which part of the detector, detected the flash), so most points centre around the middle channels. A gaussian model is applied to this, and the value for the area under the peak extracted for each histogram for

Comment: every 18s interval. These are then plotted on a graph, of time against the area under the gaussian (essentially counts in the interval), and a standard exponential decay model as mentioned above applied, y=Ae^(-kt). And that is where this question comes in. 

Hope that helps, I can go into further detail if required

Comment: Just to clarify, the target is to get the half-life (t), in second, with it's uncertainties, and to state how good a fit that is.

Comment: That helps.  But what exactly do you mean by "applied"? For instance, one can fit this model using ordinary least squares by regressing $\log(y)$ against $t$ or one can fit it using nonlinear least squares to regress $y$ against $\exp(-kt).$  The two fits will differ (slightly) and the appropriate measurements of goodness of fit will be *very* different.

Comment: This is where I came a little stuck. I used the 'NonlinearModelFit' function on Mathematica 12. But exactly the way that is done, I'm unsure, I am guessing it's the latter of the two suggestion. The documentation says :
NonlinearModelFit produces a nonlinear model of the form y(hat)=f[x_1,...,beta_1,...]  under the assumption that the original y_i are independent normally distributed with mean y(hat)_i and common standard deviation..
The link is here: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NonlinearModelFit.html

Comment: Yes, that's my recollection of this function and you're correct.  But it's probably not the best way to be fitting your data, because they essentially have Poisson-like "shot noise," which makes them (strongly) *heteroscedastic.*  They probably also have another noise component coming from the calculation of peak areas and other electronic noise sources (often Gaussian with fixed variance).  This calls for a suitably weighted least squares nonlinear fit and, associated with that, will be the analog of $R^2$ and related statistics.

Comment: Having now looked up the word 'heteroscedasticity', which must be a winner in any scrabble game, yes, it looks like that with the high variance at high x values. The gaussians themselves show a small shoulder to the left of the gaussian peak, though not much. There will be some electrical noise also, as you say. I have had using the 1/uncertainty and 1/uncertainty^2 weightings recommended to me. What would be a better way to fit this data? Would it be more fruitful to cut out fitting a gaussian at all, and just count the total number of counts in a certain interval around the peak?

Comment: Here is a question on MMa SE i have open about implementing this, that can show the data I'm using, if it helps for any reason:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240941/finding-chi2-of-a-non-linear-fit-model

Comment: A Poisson GLM with log link will do an excellent job with these data.  Its output will include various measures that can be related to goodness of fit, such as the mean "residual deviance" (which ideally should be near $1$).  In your case the mean deviance is $3.212,$ reflecting the obviously imperfect fit.  This is the analog of the "$\chi^2/dof$" value of $3.95$ reported in one answer to your other post.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thank you!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you recommend the Poisson GLM w/ log link here? Will it be a problem that the data (whilst based on poisson statistics events) are themselves not poisson statistics as it's coming from a gaussian fitting stuck over them?

Comment: The software will complain, but it's not a problem. (See https://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/.)  The Poisson GLM is perfectly suited when the SE equals the square root of the value (which is almost always the case with your data) and the log link is exactly the functional form of your model.

Comment: The SE here was worked out manually by square rooting the figure, so that's going to happen. This was advised to: 'do it manually, because with radioactivty, the SE = sqrt(N)'. Given that, does that invalidate the choice of model, or is it still good? 
Is the model form not exponential? Though I suppose the two are very similar in operation

Comment: No, it confirms the choice of model.  In fact, you never need to compute the SE with the Poisson GLM: you can ignore that (artificial, derived) variable.  The issue with the SEs is completely unrelated to whether the curve is exponential, BTW.

Comment: How is the uncertainty obtained from a poisson glm? I've met poisson statistics before, but admittedly this is the first time i've met a generalised linear model that i'm aware of.\\

Comment: I should probably clarify, that owed to the values coming from a gaussian fitting, they are not integers values (i.e. not directly counts)

Comment: Understood.  But provided the SEs are approximately equal to the square roots of the values, you will be fine.